# ts error goes away when I use arrow function but come when I not use arrow

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

Why I get this error message:

```
Type '(message?: string | undefined) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: GestureResponderEvent) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'message' and 'event' are incompatible.
    Type 'GestureResponderEvent' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

when I use the function like this:

```
  <Button onPress={handleToggleModalMessage} style={[ButtonStyles.full, s.noneBorderTop]}>
    <Text style={s.errorBtn}>Ok!</Text>
  </Button>
```

But when I use this above function in this way then I dont get an ts error:

```
  <Button onPress={() => handleToggleModalMessage()} style={[ButtonStyles.full, s.noneBorderTop]}>
    <Text style={s.errorBtn}>Ok!</Text>
  </Button>
```

can anyone explain me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example is inferring the arguments, which means it is passing in the defaults. The first example is the equivalent of this

```js
<Button onPress={(event) => handleToggleModalMessage(event)} style={[ButtonStyles.full, s.noneBorderTop]}>
        <Text style={s.errorBtn}>Ok!</Text>
</Button>
```

The type signature of `handleToggleModalMessage(event)` is incompatible with what you defined. It is expecting nothing or a string but you are passing in a `GestureResponderEvent`

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with react, so let me rephrase it in pure typescript:

```ts
type FN = (event: GestureResponderEvent) => void;

function handler(message?: string | undefined) {
  console.log(message);
}

const f1: FN = handler;          // ERROR
const f2: FN = () => handler();  // OK
```

Note that:

- `() => handler()` guarantees it will ignore any arguments passed to it
- `handler` can use its parameter, which is `message?: string | undefined`

Now consider:

```
const e: GestureResponderEvent = ...
f1(e);
f2(e);
```

Both calls are legal - both functions have type FN.
If assignment of `handler` to type `FN` was legal, it would mean that we can pass an argument of type `GestureResponderEvent` to function accepting an optional `string` - which will likely break at runtime.

Comment: thanks, so should I use @ts-ignore in this line because I dont want to use the arrow function?